# Bounded Type Parameters bounded by an annotation

Tags: java, generics, annotations

In Java, it is possible to make a bounder type parameter have to extend from a particular class or interface e.g.

```
public class Box<T extends MyClass> {
    T t
    ...
}
```

Is there anyway I can bound by an annotation so that values of T can only be classes that have a particular annotation?

Comment: I don't think you can but you could have those classes implement a marker interface (an interface with no method).

Comment: I'm pretty sure some persistence frameworks do this, and they have to do it at run time.  I think you might be able to do something with an [annotation processor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/apt/GettingStarted.html), but that would be extra-linguistic and also pretty complicated too.

Comment: Checking at run time is easy: `t.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(annotationClass)`

Answer (score 3):

Starting in Java 8, you can write

```
public class Box<T extends @MyAnno MyClass> {
...
}
```

As with any Java annotation, to enforce the semantics, you need to use an annotation processor.  The [Checker Framework](http://CheckerFramework.org/) is one annotation-processing tool that enforces the semantics for you:  you can configure it to issue an error if you ever try to instantiate the `Box` type using a type argument that lacks the `@MyAnno` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to express it in java AFAIK. `<T annotatedWith MyAnnotation>` would be so convenient in some cases, but it would add a new keyword and honestly generics are difficult enough ;)

Otherwise for an annotation, as @duckstep said it is easy to check at runtime with

```
t.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(annotationClass)
```

For an annotation processor, though, the APIs are much more tough to deal with. Here is some code if it can help some people :

```
private boolean isAnnotationPresent(TypeElement annotationTypeElement, String annotationName) {
    for (AnnotationMirror annotationOfAnnotationTypeMirror : annotationTypeElement.getAnnotationMirrors()) {
        TypeElement annotationOfAnnotationTypeElement = (TypeElement) annotationOfAnnotationTypeMirror.getAnnotationType().asElement();
        if (isSameType(annotationOfAnnotationTypeElement, annotationName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean isSameType(TypeElement annotationTypeElement, String annotationTypeName) {
    return typeUtils.isSameType(annotationTypeElement.asType(), elementUtils.getTypeElement(annotationTypeName).asType());
}
```