# Are there any nullable annotations that implicitly extend to generic types?

Tags: java, generics, nullable

I’m working in a Java project and I’ve started recently to add nullable annotations to method arguments and return values. I was wondering if there are any annotations that can be added to an argument so that it covers generic types as well. Right now I have cases similar to:

```java
Map<String, String> someMethod(Map<String, Map<String, String>> arg) {
...
}
```

That become:

```java
@NotNull
Map<@NotNull String, @NotNull String> someMethod(@NotNull Map<@NotNull String, @NotNull Map<@NotNull String, @NotNullString>> arg) {
...
}
```

Which becomes, obviously, hard to read. I’m not very familiar with the internals of Java annotations, so maybe this isn’t possible?

Comment: The syntax for this is available (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37048837/14955) but not sure if the NotNull annotations make use of that.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41006241/14955

Comment: For the sake of clarity, I’m not looking for annotations that can be used with generic types (that’s exactly the example I mentioned in my initial question), but rather an annotation such as:`@Foobar Map<String, String>` that would implicitly add `@NotNull` to keys and values.

Comment: In this case, there is no solution for your problem.

Comment: @MansenC Well, it turns out there is a solution! See Stephan Herrmann’s answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reducing the number of null annotations can be achieved with a suitable default annotation.

The following applies to annotations from [`org.eclipse.jdt.annotation_2.x`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jdt/org.eclipse.jdt.annotation/2.2.200/):

In particular [`@org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNullByDefault`](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-03/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/annotation/NonNullByDefault.html) is able to influence types in various positions, including type arguments.

So if you write:

```
@NonNullByDefault
Map<String, String> someMethod(Map<String,Map<String,String>> arg) { ...
```

this will indeed be interpreted as

```
@NonNull Map<@NonNull String, @NonNull String> someMethod(@NonNull Map<@NonNull String, @NonNull Map<@NonNull String, @NonNull String>> arg) {
```

It is even possibly to [fine-tune](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-03/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/annotation/NonNullByDefault.html#value()) the effect of `@NonNullByDefault`, and it can be applied to individual methods, or entire classes, packages or modules.

If a signature still contains a few nullable types, those need to be annotated individually as `@Nullable` in order to override the default, but those exceptions should be much fewer than the nonnull types. Note, that both `@NonNull` and `@Nullable` can be attached to types in all relevant positions, again including type arguments.

General documentation on how Eclipse interprets generics-aware null annotations can be found [in the online help](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-03/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-using_null_type_annotations.htm?cp=1_3_9_1).

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. I’ll try to add them to IDEA’s @Nullable/@NotNull inspection and see if I can get it working...

Answer (score 0):

I do not know all the possible NotNull annotations. If any of them allow `ElementType.TYPE_PARAMETER`, then they should be able to annotate generics.

If not, just implement the following annotation:

```java
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE_PARAMETER)
public @interface NotNull {}
```

and add more element types if you want to use this annotation in other regards than only generics.
If you want to use the annotation during runtime, through reflection, then you have to change the RetentionPolicy to `RUNTIME`.

Comment: I think my question led to a some confusion (and possibly a duplicated question). I’ve added a comment for clarification.

Comment: Also note that `TYPE_PARAMETER` relates to type parameter *declarations*. What is discussed here is the effect on actual type *arguments*, which are covered by the constant `TYPE_USE`.